# jQuery Mobile: Spacing the widgets in a page

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using a grouped-buttons-widget and a listview-widget. My code is

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-corner-all ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-horizontal">
    <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls" align="center">
        <!-- ........ -->        
    </div>        
</div>

<ul data-role="listview" id="mylist">
    <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading" data-theme="b">
        Sheet: Untitled1
    </li>
    <!-- ........ -->
    <li id="mylistSummary" data-role="list-divider" role="heading" data-theme="b">
        Total:
    </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is now the widgets appear just next to each other without any spacing in between.

[image]

What should I do to ensure desired space between these (and perhaps other) widgets?

Comment: You really should look into learning to use the developer tools you can get with browsers. The built-in developer tools in Chrome are amazing and let you figure-out all this menial CSS stuff you keep asking for...

Comment: @Jasper, thanks for your valuable comment. Do I need some existing samples to inspect with the developer tools in order to understand how to solve my problems? I found this link to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview). But what I am looking for is a standard way of putting widgets at relative positions from each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may try to add a simple `<br>` to separate the 2 components:

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-corner-all ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-horizontal">
    <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls" align="center">
        <!-- ........ -->        
    </div>        
</div>

<br>

<ul data-role="listview" id="mylist">
    <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading" data-theme="b">
        Sheet: Untitled1
    </li>
    <!-- ........ -->
    <li id="mylistSummary" data-role="list-divider" role="heading" data-theme="b">
        Total:
    </li>
</ul>
```

Or you may try to play with `margin-bottom`, for example, try the following:

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 5px;" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-corner-all ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-horizontal">
    <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls" align="center">
        <!-- ........ -->        
    </div>        
</div>

<ul data-role="listview" id="mylist">
    <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading" data-theme="b">
        Sheet: Untitled1
    </li>
    <!-- ........ -->
    <li id="mylistSummary" data-role="list-divider" role="heading" data-theme="b">
        Total:
    </li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps.

Let me know if these solutions work for you.

Comment: Thanks @Littm, I initially used <br> and <p> to fix it. But 'margin-botttom' is much better.